# Create-React-App: ESlint error while deployment on local machine

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, create-react-app, eslint

I am using create-react-app (React v16.12.0). I am getting following error when I run `'npm start'` on mac.

```
[1] There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
[1] It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
[1]
[1] The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
[1]
[1]   "eslint": "^6.6.0"
[1]
[1] Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
[1] However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:
[1]
[1]   /Users/abz/node_modules/eslint (version: 6.5.1)
[1]
[1] Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
[1]
[1] If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[1] That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
[1]
[1] To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
[1]
[1]   1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
[1]   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
[1]   3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
[1]   4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
[1]
[1] In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
[1] If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
[1]
[1]   5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
[1]      This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
[1]
[1]   6. Check if /Users/abz/node_modules/eslint is outside your project directory.
[1]      For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
[1]
[1]   7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
[1]      This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.
[1]
[1] If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
[1] That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
[1]
[1] P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
[1]
[1] react-scripts start exited with code 1
```

I googled and found

1. following solution suggested by many

   - Delete the `eslint and babel-eslint` from `users/abz/node_modules/`folder
   - Delete `package.json-lock, node_modules` from local project
   - Run `npm install` and `npm start`

   **I tried it and this solution didn't work for me.**
2. This issue can be mitigated by using

   ```
   adding an `.env file` in root folder with statement `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`
   ```

   **But, it is not the solution for this problem.**

Any help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

it happens because there is a dependency installed at a parent level which has different version. In your case it's `/Users/abz/node_modules/eslint`. Just run this command from root

```
rm -rf node_modules/eslint
```

and this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Anuj. After deleting eslint, it asked for couple of similar version mismatches. I deleted all using same command above.

Comment: After running the command, even though the app was running fine there were warnings saying : "failed to load plugin 'import' declared in 'baseconfig cannot find module 'eslint'".
And updating the npm to latest version [npm install -g npm@latest] and then npm start worked well.
 [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682650/reactjs-module-build-error)

Comment: Thanks so much this worked for me. But my other question is, if I delete this folder will the eslint work when I run ```npx eslint .```

Answer (score 3):

following Anuj shah & SHAHBAZ replies:

1. `rm -rf node_modules/eslint`
2. `npm install -g npm@latest`

or just do `npm i -S fsevents`

resolved this issue.

but i have to do the above steps again and again whenever i install another package. this is so frustrating...

does anyone have a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following steps and solved the problem...

1. Delete node_modules, package-lock.json / yarn.lock
2. Add "eslint": "^6.6.0" to your devDependencies
3. Run npm install / yarn
4. Run the eslint --init command
5. Install the eslint plugins you need

Answer (score 0):

At the root of my C drive, I located and deleted the node_modules folder, since this was pointed out as the folder housing the eslint-lint that conflicted with the one in my project. That did the magic!

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple different versions of react-script. Update them to use the same version at it should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

just run

```
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@4.0.3
```

or

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@4.0.3
```

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me
npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@latest --force

Comment: Please give the [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) a read to improve your answer and give you some insight on how to write better answers in the future. As it is currently written, your answer is hard to understand because the text is difficult to differentiate from your recommended shell command.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick less technical hack, to avoid messing with the node_nodules you can just switch root directory of your application

So if your application root is like so

```
 Users/Parent-folder/Current-app
```

move into into this root instead

```
 Users/Current-app
```

and run `npm install/yarn` and `npm run dev/start` or `yarn dev/start`

this will avoid your application node-modules to conflict with whatever your parent folders modules.

Answer (score -5):

Just run:

```
npm uninstall eslint
```

Error will be gone.

*Note: `npm uninstall -g eslint` did not work in my case*