# Getting error after upgrading eslint version

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I have setup eslint+prettier+husky in my react opensource project. When I ran npm start after setting up it is showing me this error message.

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "^6.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/rishipurwar/coding-space/node_modules/eslint (version: 7.32.0) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/rishipurwar/coding-space/node_modules/eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! codingspace@0.1.0 start: `npm run watch:css && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the codingspace@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the error just try one of these

```
  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
```

Comment: this will remove eslint latest version.
Then eslint will not work properly. I tried to do that

Comment: Manually changing eslint version in create react app is not recommended you can run npm eject if you want to do manual config.

Comment: I think I need to update reac-script but I am not sure.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124662/create-react-app-eslint-error-while-deployment-on-local-machine

Comment: That might work but create react app never supports latest version of any module iirc. only way of changing package versions manually is by ejecting create react app.